# How to draw Google Maps circle overlays with fixed radius?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps API v3 to draw circle overlays at specific locations (latitude and longitude) provided by user via text field (simple HTML and JavaScript). The problem is, when I input different latitudes and longitudes, the size of the overlay circle changes. Even though I've provided a fixed-radius for the circles. I don't know how to fix this problem. I've tried using "scale" instead of "radius" but was unable to do so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create circle in google map v3 with same radius in all zoom level?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617998/how-to-create-circle-in-google-map-v3-with-same-radius-in-all-zoom-level)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the projection used by the google maps API the same radius will appear different sizes at different latitudes.  Do you need a fixed radius or a fixed size in pixels? They are not the same.

For a fixed pixel size circle see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617998/how-to-create-circle-in-google-map-v3-with-same-radius-in-all-zoom-level)
(from the "Related" questions on the right)

Comment: I need fixed sized in pixels, yeah. But I need to be able to increase and decrease that size dynamically (using JavaScript/AJAX). How can draw an overlay with specified pixels instead of radius?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Have implemented it successfully.

Comment: @BasitSaeed Hi, I also got the same problem with yours and so how did you manage to solve it? It would be great if you can share here. Thanks

Comment: Whoa! That was 3 years ago and I have mostly forgotten the source code. I do remember using `scale` property while initializing the marker. You can try that, maybe?